# How to get "copy as cURL" in the script?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

There is a feature called "Copy as cURL" from the browsers in Developer Mode with a network tab.
I can get that copy of cURL headers by clicking mouse.

Is it possible to get the result from the shell without GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `curl` from the command line.  `curl -I <URL>` should do the trick to only get the headers, or `curl -i <URL>` if you want the headers along with the payload.  For other options see `man curl` or `curl --help` from the command lien.

Comment: No, my question was to get "Copy as cURL" result. which is getting more data than just -I alone.

Comment: I edited the response to make it more clear.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I appreciate you for the response, however that's not what I am looking for. 'Copy as cURL'  looks like --   
curl 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=66d35b71bef3' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0' -H 'Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'

Comment: So did you get what you needed? I guess I was confused. It sounded like you were looking for the *response* headers.  The headers listed after your `-H` flag are the *request* headers that your machine sent.  There is no difference in the response between calling the generic `curl <URL>` versus `curl <URL> -H <headers listed in your comment>`.

Comment: I'm trying to emulate the same responded situation with the other machine, I could copy as cURL and it gives me the same result the original machine received but now I rather have it script instead of physically drag and click to copy those.